# How can I delete all files with a particular extension in a particular folder?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, rm

If I set the current/working directory (navigating to it using `cd`) to some particular directory and then type:

```
rm *.xvg
```

What will this command do?  Is it true that the above command will **only** delete files with the extension `.xvg` **only** in the working directory?

I was nervous about trying this before asking, because I want to be absolutely sure that the above command will only delete `.xvg` files ***LOCATED IN THE WORKING DIRECTORY***.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, `rm *.xvg` will *only* delete the files with the specified extension in your *current* directory.

A *good* way to make sure you are indeed in the directory you want delete your files is to use the `pwd` command which will display your current directory and then do an `ls` to verify you find the files you are expecting.

If you are bit apprehensive about issuing the `rm` command, there are 2 things you can do:

1. type `ls *.xvg` to see a list of what files would be affected by this command.
2. Unless you have a *lot* of files, you could always also use the `-i` command line switch for `rm` (also exists for `cp` and `mv`). Using `rm -i *.xvg` would prompt you for each individual file if it was ok to delete it, so you could be sure nothing you didn't expect was getting deleted. (This will be tedious if you have a lot of files though :)

Comment: Also: `rm -f {*.xvg,.*.xvg}` to remove also hidden files. And `rm -R -f {*.xvg,.*.xvg}` to remove also directories.

Answer (score 45):

You don't need to navigate to the dir, just use

```
rm /some/dir/*.xvg
```

In the case you have a typo or similar mistake in the path, where /som/dir does not exist:

```
cd /som/dir
rm *.xvg
```

will accidentally delete all .xvg-files in the current dir. The first command will not, and you don't need to cd back again.

An alternative way would be to use find:

```
find /some/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.xvg" -delete
```

Comment: find /some/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.xvg" -delete worked for me!
use -maxdepth "n" to delete matching files in sub directory if given path

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `rm *.xvg` will only delete files ending with `.xvg` in your current directory. Here's why.

When you type a command like this, work is split up between the shell you are using (let's assume bash) and the command binary.

You can locate the binary by typing `which rm`. This little program takes care of unlinking files. Programs like this can be started from the command line and can read a list of arguments `prog arg1 arg2 arg3` when they start up. In the case of `rm`, they are interpreted as a list of fully qualified filenames to be deleted. So if you are in a directory containing the file `foo.bar`, typing `delete 'foo.*'` will result in `rm: foo.*: No such file or directory`. Note the single quotes around the file pattern, they tell the shell to pass the argument to the shell as it is.

However if you type `rm *.bar` in the same directory, it will delete the file. What's happening here is that your shell, which is the program you are using to type in commands, is performing some transformations before passing the arguments on to the command. One of these is called 'file name expansion', otherwise know as 'globbing'. You can see a list of bash file name expansions [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). One of the most common expansions is `*`, which is expanded to filenames in the current directory.

A simple way to look at globs at work is to use `echo`, which prints back all arguments passed to it through the shell. So typing `echo *` in the same directory will output `foo.bar`. So when you type `rm *.bar`, what's actually happening is that the shell expands the argument list to `foo.bar`, then passes that to the `rm` command.

There are some ways of controlling globbing. In recent versions of bash, for example, you can turn on an option called globstar which will do recursive expansion. Typing `echo **/*.bar` will show a list of all files ending in `.bar` in all subfolders. So typing `rm **/*.bar` in globstar enabled bash will indeed recursively delete all matching files in subfolders.

Answer (score 2):

Command :

```
  rm ./*.pgm
```

works for me

Command:

```
rm *.pgm
```

gives error command ( in Polish, translated  ):

```
rm: wrong option - '1'
Use "rm ./-1000.pgm" to delete the file '-1000.pgm'.
Write "rm --help" for information.
```

in

```
bash --version
GNU bash, wersja 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```