# delete all .swp file using rm command

Tags: linux, grep, rm

I am trying to find and delete all `.swp` files in my current directory. I was using below command:

```
rm -i `find . | grep .swp$`
```

But everytime it is giving me this error:

```
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

Anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: see also [How can I delete all files with a particular extension in a particular folder?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42020)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to delete files in your current directory, or in your current directory and all its subdirs?

Answer (score 11):

The error message you received probably indicates that no file matched the name pattern `.swp$`. A generally safer way to do what you wrote (because it will handle any file name):

```
find . -name '*.swp' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -i --
```

In the snippet above, I used `-print0` so that `find` separates
records with null characters; the default is newlines, which
unfortunately is valid within a filename. With `-print0`, the command
works works with any filenames, including any that embed
newlines. Likewise, `xargs -0` processes its input as null-separated
records.

Answer (score 10):

Or a variation with `find` alone e.g.:

```
find . -name "*.swp" -ok rm {} +
```

or just without confirmation (WARNING!):

```
find . -name "*.swp" -delete
```

Comment: Hah, I was thinking of posting the same, but then figured I would wait for comments, if any :). Note that POSIX find doesn't support closing a `-ok` command with `+`; I would write `-ok rm -- {} \;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the POSIX hint! I'm on OSX atm so I expected other limitations anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Always use the simplest tool for the job. As you want to operate on the current directory only, this command will work fine:

`rm -i *.swp`

Comment: This command is different from what the OP is doing, since `find` by default will recurse into subdirectories to find matching files.

Comment: The OP wrote, verbatim: "I am trying to find and delete all .swp files in my current directory."  He didn't specify that he wants to delete files in subdirectories also.  As per OP's specifications, the `rm` command I posted is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more restricted, you can use this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.swp" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: -0 for using `exec`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant What's wrong with using `exec`?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes swap files don't have `.swp` extension only. It may have `saw`, `swb`, `swp`, etc extensions as well.

```
sushil@batpod:/app/DDB# ls -a
.gui.py.swo
gui.py
.serializers.py.swp
serializers.py
.tcinfo.py.swm
tcinfo.py
.views.py.swb
views.py
```

and so on...

I have created one command which deletes almost all swap files with extension `sw*`

Command:

```
find . -name '*.sw\*' | xargs -i rm {}
```

***NOTE***: Before executing above command first have a look at the files command is going to delete, using

```
find . -name '*.sw\*'
```

Hope you don't delete some important files.